# how to replace string from given offset?

Tags: php

I need only one replacement of a string within a string, but since string that am intend to replace is repeated in the haystack I need to precise start pointer and how many times replacement should be done. I did not found any mention of start offstet if php's string replace functions.

Comment: -php5.3 This has nothing to do w/ PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

```
str_replace(substr($string,$start),$replace)
```

Comment: only if there  are none after

Comment: This solution will work on old version of PHP. for the versions >= 5.6 use **str_replace(find,replace,string,count)** syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can use substr, for instance :

```
$str = "This This This";
echo substr($str, 0, 6) . str_replace('This', 'That', substr($str, 6)); // This This That
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some other functions than `str_replace` that supports a limited search, for example [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($search, '/').'/', $replacement, $str, 1)
```

Or a combination of [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) and [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
implode($replacement, explode($search, $str, 2))
```